# Ubuntu in VMware player won't detect multiple screens anymore

Tags: 16.04, multiple-monitors, vmware-player

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 running inside VMPlayer 7.0.0 (on Windows 7), and I don't see any of my screens (I'm using 3: the laptop's built-in and two via hdmi).

I'm running `open-vm-tools`, `open-vm-tools-desktop` and `open-vm-tools-dev`.

[image: Screens are not detected]

Any idea ?

Comment: The VM can't see the actual hardware on the host OS.  It's only going to be able to see the 'virtual' hardware passed to it.  That is to say, it's not capable of detecting the hardware on the host, and will not show the screens on the host machine.  To use those monitors it'd have to be installed to the hard drive and booted to, not running from within a VM.  (This is due to how virtualization works, unfortunately)

Comment: Yes that's exactly the purpose ov the so called "tools", which are properly installed (see my question).  Anyway, the VM was correctly detecting the screens before, this buggy behavior is new.

Comment: The tools don't solve this... not directly.  You may wish to read through [VMware documentation](https://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.ws.using.doc%2FGUID-E51CADFC-31C3-491F-92D9-C9C1D9615668.html) on this for making 'multiple monitors' work - note this doesn't make it 'work' as you expect ot to, really, as you have to full-screen the Ubuntu VM to really make it work, I believe.

Comment: I did already; I've been trying to figure out this problem for weeks. Yes the VM has to be full screen in order to expand it to multiple monitors.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: This should work and did < 16.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue with the kernel that ships with Ubuntu 16.04 (4.4, I believe), in combination with `open-vm-tools`.
Upgrading the kernel to 4.6 fixed this issue for me.

Here are the upgrade steps:
http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/05/install-linux-kernel-4-6-ubuntu-16-04/

Comment: Oh god, you've just ended up days and days of frustrating attempts to fix this.  Thanks A BUNCH !